# Anomalous data detection with density function

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, density-function

I have a very simple exercise from my class for which I need some intuition regarding some quote by the professor.

Imagine we have the weights of a number of people and we compute its (non-parametric) density function obtaining:

[image]

Then the comment by my professor was:

> We have a unimodal distribution which we can take as being normal. We
>   detect anomalous data because the probability of an element not being
>   in the normal is less than 0.05.

Do you understand this reasoning? To me is totally unclear. Assuming normality is not so bad. But for the other part I think I have to look for an specific part of the graph which I don't know...

Comment: Once you assume normality, you have access to the normal distribution numbers. A typical way of defining anomalous data is to declare anything anomalous if its probability of occurring, as defined by the normal distribution, is less than $0.05$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister i know it is very basic, but given the density of the image how do you see that there are points with probability less than 0.05

Comment: @AdrianKeister so for instance being less than 40 is anomalous in my situation?

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure what "Density" means in your problem. I will say that once you assume normality, the original data curve you have here is irrelevant, except for determining the mean and standard deviation of the normal curve you're now going to work with. The standard tables give you the probabilities.

Comment: @AdrianKeister oh, I see. then, the mean is obviously located near the peak, but how do you deduce graphically the variance, this is something i have asked myself several times, thank you

Comment: Graphically, on a normal distribution, the standard deviation is the horizontal distance from the peak to either inflection point (up or down from the mean). If you have the raw data, of course, you can simply compute the standard deviation.

Comment: @AdrianKeister if you want to make the comments above into an answer i can edit the details in a couple of days, thanks very much

Comment: You need to change professors if that density is considered "gaussian" and that data in a tail region must be considered anomalous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you assume normality, you have access to the normal distribution numbers. A typical way of defining anomalous data is to declare anything anomalous if its probability of occurring, as defined by the normal distribution, is less than $0.05.$

I'm not quite sure what "Density" means in your problem. I will say that once you assume normality, the original data curve you have here is irrelevant, except for determining the mean and standard deviation of the normal curve you're now going to work with. The standard tables give you the probabilities.

Graphically, on a normal distribution, the standard deviation is the horizontal distance from the peak to either inflection point (up or down from the mean). If you have the raw data, of course, you can simply compute the standard deviation.